# Firefox display "EOF" after npm start

Tags: reactjs

I'm following the w3schools tutorial on react.

So the first thing I'm told to do is to create the create-react-app : `npm install -g create-react-app`

Then create a React application named myfirstreact : `npx create-react-app myfirstreact`

The app get created and every thing seems good at this point.

Now I'm asked to Run the React Application by doing the following: `cd myfirstreact` and `npm start`, and this is what the Terminal display

> myfirstreact@0.1.0 start /root/myfirstreact

> react-scripts start

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view myfirstreact in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.43.128:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

No new window gets opened in Firefox, nothing happens.

So I open the link `http://localhost:3000` on Firefox and all I got is "EOF", I check the page source and the only thing there is is : EOF (which is the same thing I get If I access `http://localhost:3000` on Firefox without starting react  )

And what I want is to get the default react app.

**Edit: I just downloaded Opera browser and when tried, The app works just fine. So the problem seems to be a Firefox problem.**

Here you can see all the screenshots.

[Terminal 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwSD5.png)

[Terminal 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEo28.png)

[Terminal 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NwtZ.png)

[Browser "EOF"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsZej.png)

Comment: Where are you getting EOF

Comment: on the browser page

Comment: Have u checked the console for errors?

Comment: yes,  there no errors .

Comment: Try recompiling your project and then: `cd [your path] && npm start`.

Also check your react files if there's something in it

Comment: Did it several times, I even reinstalled the global react and I get the same thing. 
The react files are on default.

Comment: I don't know what it could be. Maybe a screenshot would help

Comment: It's possible that there might be a previous service worker that's responding to your request. In devtools, clear cache and all storage. In `Application > Storage` click on `Clear site data`, if you're using Chrome.

Comment: @testing_22 I just added screenshots.

Comment: @maazadeeb I cleared the everything and nothing happened. But I downloaded another browser "opera" and the app is working fine there. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed Firefox, Started the app all over again `npm start`. And for some reason the app is working now